# ERROR TypeError: newAsBuilt.asBuiltWoList is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I had found what I thought was a good example of what I am trying to do here on stackoverflow and that I was following the example.  However, when I run my code I am getting the error in the title.

In the application I am working on, I am receiving an array where I receive from the back end service 0 to many child records.  I am now working on code so that only updated records are added to an array that is sent to the backend service.  I am trying to create an array of the child records within the parent record.

The code I have is below:

```
export class AsBuilt {
    model?: string;
    eff?: string;
    endItem?: string;
    naPartNo?: string;
    partNo?: string;
    woSeq?: string;
    serialNo?: string;
    parentSerialNo?: string;
    altPartNo?: string;
    asBuiltVeoNo?: string;
    refDesg?: string;
    modDate?: string;
    asBuiltCl?: string;
    lotNo?: string;
    asBuiltQty?: string;
    expDate?: string;
    modUser?: string;
    comments?: string;
    partStatusId?: string;
    partStatusDesc?: string;
    fltCrit?: string;
    asBuiltWoList?: AsBuiltWO[];
}

export class AsBuiltWO {
    woSeq?: string;
    workOrder?: string;
    operation?: string;
    instId?: string;
    wad?: string;
}
```

```
newAsBuilt.model = this.dataSource.data[this.ecIn].asBuiltList[this.abIn].model,
newAsBuilt.eff = this.dataSource.data[this.ecIn].asBuiltList[this.abIn].eff,
newAsBuilt.endItem = this.dataSource.data[this.ecIn].asBuiltList[this.abIn].endItem,
newAsBuilt.partNo = this.dataSource.data[this.ecIn].asBuiltList[this.abIn].partNo,
newAsBuilt.naPartNo = this.dataSource.data[this.ecIn].asBuiltList[this.abIn].naPartNo,
newAsBuilt.parentSerialNo = this.asBuiltForm.get('parentSerialNo').value,
newAsBuilt.asBuiltCl = this.asBuiltForm.get('asBuiltCl').value,
newAsBuilt.altPartNo = this.asBuiltForm.get('altPartNo').value,
newAsBuilt.asBuiltVeoNo = this.asBuiltForm.get('asBuiltVeoNo').value,
newAsBuilt.asBuiltQty = this.asBuiltForm.get('asBuiltQty').value,
newAsBuilt.serialNo = this.asBuiltForm.get('serialNo').value,
newAsBuilt.lotNo = this.asBuiltForm.get('lotNo').value,
newABWo = new AsBuiltWO;
newABWo.woSeq  = this.dataSource.data[this.ecIn].asBuiltList[this.abIn].woSeq,
newABWo.workOrder = this.dataSource.data[this.ecIn].asBuiltList[this.abIn].asBuiltWoList[0].workOrder,
newAsBuilt.asBuiltWoList.push(newABWo);
```

When I try to add newABWo to newAsBuilt I am getting an error on that line

```
ERROR TypeError: newAsBuilt.asBuiltWoList is undefined
```

I am guessing there is something simple I have missed, but I am not seeing it right now.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out what I needed to do on my own.  When I changed the code from:

```
newAsBuilt.asBuiltWoList.push(newABWo);
```

to

```
newAsBuilt.asBuiltWoList = new Array(newABWo);
```

I am thinking once I have the array initialized, I can then push additional records onto it.